# ImageView muestra imagen tomada con CameraX rotada

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

Estoy creando una aplicación de cámara con kotlin y CameraX, quiero mostrar la foto tomada en un ImageView pero esta se muestra rotada

hice una prueba con una imagen y la coloca con la orientacion correcta(imagen 1), pero cuando envió la foto que acabo de tomar esta la muestra rotada(imagen 2) , la foto en el explorador de archivos tiene la orientación correcta, el imageView esta abajo en la esquina izquierda

Mi Layout es este

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view_finder"></androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>
```

el código para colocar la imagen en el imageView **imagen 1**

```
override fun onImageSaved(file: File) {
                    val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: ${file.absolutePath}"
                    Log.d("CameraXApp", msg)
                    viewFinder.post {
                        Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        val uriImagen: Uri = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.ange1d.camerax/119e1c.jpg")
                        preView?.setImageURI(uriImagen)

                    }
                }
```

mi código para colocar la foto en el imageView **imagen 2**

```
private var preView: ImageView? = null

//override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
preView = findViewById(R.id.preview)

//findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.capture_button).setOnClickListener {
override fun onImageSaved(file: File) {
                    val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: ${file.absolutePath}"
                    Log.d("CameraXApp", msg)
                    viewFinder.post {
                        Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        val uriImagen: Uri = Uri.parse(file.absolutePath)
                        preView?.setImageURI(uriImagen)

                    }
                }
```

**imagen1**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**imagen 2**

[image: imagen2]

**imagen 3** ambas imágenes están en  forma vertical pero la de la izquierda(fotografía que tomo con la aplicacion) se muestra de manera horizontal en el imageView

[image: comparacion]

mi codigo completo esta en [CameraX](https://github.com/Ange1D/CameraX)

Comment: "funciona bien, pero en el explorador de archivos tiene la orientación correcta" , entonces cual sería el problema?

Comment: Modifique la pregunta, el problema es que la foto la guarda con la orientación correcta pero al enviarla al imageView esta aparece rotada

Comment: Revisando el código que compartes, solo toma foto y aparece una prevista en la parte inferior, no puedo ver lo que muestras en la segunda foto.

Comment: Exacto al tomar la foto la coloca en la prevista pero de manera horizontal como si la estuviera girando  la fotografía 90 grados, Añadí una imagen mas para que se aprecie la comparación